# How to reload dom elements on Firestore db change?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

We are building an app, using vue.js, vuefire, and Firestore, where a User has multiple Restaurants. In our Dashboard, then need to be able to "switch" between restaurants to make changes (For example, updating a menu). The problem is that on the "Menu" layout, when I switch restaurants, then menu doesn't change.

We have a Switcher component that changes a user's "activeRestaurant" both in the db and also in the vuex store.

Here is the relevant code from store.js:

```
switchRestaurant({ commit }, payload) {
  console.log(payload)
  db.collection('users').doc(payload.id).update({
    activeRestaurant: payload.activeRestaurant,
  })
  const activeRest = {
    activeRestaurant: payload.activeRestaurant,
    id: payload.id,
  }
  commit('setUser', activeRest)
}
```

On our Menu Layout, the menu items are rendered with:

```
<li v-for="(regularItem, idx) in regularItems" :key="idx">
    <h4>{{ regularItem.item.name }}</h4>
</li>
```

and

```
computed: {
  userAccount () {
    return this.$store.getters.user
  }
},
firestore () {
  return {
    user: db.collection('users').doc(this.userAccount.id),
    regularItems: db.collection('items').where("restaurant", "==", 
    this.userAccount.activeRestaurant.id)
  }
},
```

If I switch from Restaurant A to Restaurant B, nothing changes. But, if I then navigate to another Layout, it renders the content for Restaurant B. If I then click back to my Menu, it shows the Menu Items for Restaurant B.

How can I make it so that my Menu content changes from Restaurant A to B when I switch Restaurants?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VueFire is not making another call to the database when the activeRestaurantId is changed. You can re-write this code in a method to update when that variable changes like so:

```
data () {
  return {
    'regularItems': []
  }
}
methods: {
  updateActiveRestaurant () {
    db.collection('items').where("restaurant", "==", this.userAccount.activeRestaurant.id)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        var item = doc.data()
        item.id = doc.id
        this.regularItems.push(item)
      }.bind(this))
    }.bind(this))
  }
}
```

And then you can add a call to this function on created and after the activeRestaurant data changes.

Comment: Thanks Dylan... still struggling with this. How would I manage it where my switcher and my menuItems are different components?